# How to delete accounts in gerrit (3.0)

Tags: git, gerrit

I am having trouble with some accounts (I created them using ssh I think so they cannot log in unless `development_become_any_account` is active.) They get a blank login page now.

I would like to reset these by deleting them, plus recreate them. I am using HTTP Auth if that matters.

I have inspected the user configuration when cloning All-Users and checking out origin/users/self but I really cannot see any difference that may be causing this.

I would really appreciate help with how I go about deleting the bad accounts so that I can start over.

**Update**

I have noted that the accounts created through ssh never get a "gerrit:" identity. I cannot seem to add a gerrit: identity to accounts - is this possible to do after account creation?

I tried to delete the "accounts/self" ref from All-Users but that ended up making the account unusable but with the username still taken in gerrit, so that wasn't a solution.

Comment: Hope this can help you out (I had a similar problem) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116440/cannot-login-after-editing-email-addresses/58130525#58130525

Comment: Thank you - this is actually how I ended up solving it as well! Took me some experimentation heh. Did not post a response here of my solution since it was not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Checkout `All-Users` project from gerrit

```
git clone ssh://<user>@<gerrit host>:29418/All-Users
```

2. Checkout ref `refs/meta/external-ids`

```
git fetch origin refs/meta/external-ids:refs/meta/external-ids
git checkout refs/meta/external-ids
```

3. Search the account you want to delete, e.g. `foobar`

```
grep -r foobar *

398cd83a701a63c77dfc1998f76524561208c879:[externalId "gerrit:foobar"]
398cd83a701a63c77dfc1998f76524561208c879:   email = foobar@example.com
9b622a00bcd48295d545ba946afdd91df8b0ed61:[externalId "username:foobar"]
```

4. Delete those files and commit

```
git rm 398cd83a701a63c77dfc1998f76524561208c879 9b622a00bcd48295d545ba946afdd91df8b0ed61
git commit -m "Remove account foobar"
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/external-ids
```

Comment: Did this actually work?????.

I'm seeing a whole bunch of directories and no code as shown in the output

Comment: It did work for me. @anishanil There won't be "directories" in the `All-Users` project after you check out `refs/meta/external-ids`. There may be many files with a hex filename of length 40. Each of these files represents a single user.

Comment: Should i delete all these folders

Comment: The command should be "git grep foobar *"

Comment: There won't be folders. There should be only files. You should delete thoses files which contain the account name you wanna delete.

Comment: Perhaps things have changed. I'm using Gerrit 3.3.2 and when I checkout refs/meta/external-ids I get lots two-hexadecimal-character-named directories under which there are the files containing the user information. So, the command to find the correct files is "grep -r foobar .".

Comment: Just for information, you can add the "gerrit:" external ID to an existing account by using the same technique i.e. create a new external ID file on the refs/meta/external-ids branch which defines the gerrit: external ID.  This will allow users whose accounts were created with the "gerrit create-account" CLI command to log in.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do it would be to use the Account Endpoints of Gerrit's [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-accounts.html) to inactivate the user. You can do it like this, from the command line:

```
$ curl -u user:password -X DELETE https://gerrit.example.net/a/accounts/{accound-id}/active
```

The `{account-id}` piece is explained [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-accounts.html#account-id).

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Gerrit 3.6.1, you can add the `account` plugin and delete an account via SSH.  The following is the required syntax:

```
ssh -p 29418 ssh://<user_name>@<host_name> account delete ACCOUNT-ID --yes-really-delete ACCOUNT-NAME
```

You can retrieve the ACCOUNT-ID by using the `admin-console` plugin and running the following:

```
ssh -p 29418 ssh://<user_name>@<host_name> admin-console ls-users|grep <user_to_delete>
```

Note: This method will still leave the ACCOUNT-ID record of the user in the database, but the user will be set as inactive with their information removed.