# How to create a Gerrit LDAP user via REST API?

Tags: rest, gerrit

We need to migrate around 800 LDAP-integrated user accounts from Gerrit 2.13.6 (using reviewDB for account data storage) to Gerrit 3.0.2 (using git NoteDB for user data storage). We decided to use Gerrit's REST API to do that, as it seemed the easiest solution for this task.

We can easily pull the data of all 800 accounts from Gerrit 2.13.6, but we have issues trying to create a single working LDAP-integrated account in Gerrit 3.0.2.
We've tried creating an account (let's call it Foo Bar, with login foobar) via Gerrit REST account creation method and it works fine, except the external-ids of the new account look like this:

```
[
  {
    "identity": "username:foobar",
    "trusted": true
  },
  {
    "identity": "mailto:FBar@company.com",
    "email_address": "FBar@company.com",
    "trusted": true,
    "can_delete": true
  }
]
```

instead of how they should look like below, for proper, existing, LDAP-integrated accounts:

```
[
  {
    "identity": "username:foobar",
    "trusted": true
  },
  {
    "identity": "gerrit:foobar",
    "email_address": "FBar@company.com",
    "trusted": true,
    "can_delete": true
  }
]
```

The wrong identity above (mailto:FBar@company.com) doesn't allow the account to properly login via LDAP (Authentication failed, can't create a new account with email in use - so he doesn't even recognize this account as one he should integrate with LDAP).

What we've already tried:
1) Gerrit REST API account methods - it doesn't have any methods for adding/updating external ids to correct that
2) Confirming the email of the created user (as it looks like an email to be confirmed, but doesn't generate an actual confirmation email) via API  - this doesn't change anything for the faulty identity
3) Creating accounts without an email (the faulty identity doesn't get created) and then adding the preferred email with a "no_confirmation" flag - this again creates the faulty identity
4) Deleting external ids - deleting the faulty identity renders us unable to login to the account. Deleting both identities causes Gerrit to create a duplicate account on First login (as the email was now unique)

What we tried and did work - first answer from this topic:
[Cannot login after editing email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116440/cannot-login-after-editing-email-addresses). This involves: 
- Cloning the external-ids branch from All-Users repository
- Modifying the faulty identity for the created user
- Renaming the external id file to a new SHA1 hash that matches the modified identity name
- Pushing the change
After this change, the LDAP user can actually login to his account created on the backend as normal.

But the solution above is very hacky and not automation-friendly. It's hard to believe it's the only available solution.

Does anyone know of a better solution for this problem?

Comment: did you find  a way to do this via the REST API? We are in the same boat with an OAuth integration.